# Using Java Native (Class Library) Jar in Android Studio project

Tags: java, android, netbeans, jar, android-gradle-plugin

I have class libraries I've developed in Netbeans, for java native applications. I would like to use this functionalities in Android app project, instead of writing the whole code again.
I know how to create Jar in netbeans and add it as a dependency(or even a separate module)  in the android project.
but it seems I cannot use the code when I call the related function explicitly.

Let's say I have the following Scheme in Netbeans:

> CommonLogicLayer (Class Library)
>
> ```
> --->SourcesPackages
>    ---><default package>
>        --->FileTest
> ```
>
> Inside fileTest.java I have function named: `Test(String fullPath)` that gets the path of a file and print its content. very simple.

After building the library (for Jar file), I insert the jar in *libs* folder, compile the android app, and in *onCreate* function I tried to call the jar like that:

`CommonLogicLayer.FileTest.Test("c:\\text.txt")`

Even though, the builder (Gradle File) add  *CommonLogicLayer* as a dependency:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':utilitiesandroid')
compile project(':commonutilities')
compile project(':CommonLogicLayer')
```

}

I cannot use its functions as I desire.

I also tried adding the jar as a Module, and add this module as a dependency, but still no results.

So my question is:

1. Can Android studio has java native libraries that are not (android studio/Eclipse)
2. If 1 is 'Yes', what am I doing wrong?
3. If 1 is 'No', what is the work around for it instead of replicate the code?

Much Obliged!

Comment: if you build your library with maven or gradle, you can add them as dependencies as usual after they're installed to the local .m2 repo

Comment: Could you be more specific? how do I add Gradle file to netbean project? and how do i tell the compiler to use that gradle file? and How do i Tell android project to look at the gradle file once I add this project as an external library?